# http working but https being timed out on nginx server

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

I'm running an nginx server. For some reason https://abhaysrivastav.net is timing out.

http://abhaysrivastav.net is redirecting to https as per the configured rule.

Also for https requests i'm not getting any logs in error.log or access.log file, only for http requests logs are coming. Below is my parsed nginx configuration file.

I have already checked 443 port is open in security group. Tested from this tool https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ also. Port seems to be open.

Can someone please help ?

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf:
server {
    server_name  abhaysrivastav.net www.abhaysrivastav.net;
    root /home/ubuntu/Website;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abhaysrivastav.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abhaysrivastav.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}


server {
        server_name  youtubecut.com www.youtubecut.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/youtubecut-frontend/dist;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abhaysrivastav.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abhaysrivastav.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name abhaysrivastav.net youtubecut.com www.abhaysrivastav.net www.youtubecut.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```

Comment: Have you also got a firewall on the server?

Comment: No firewall. Strangely it was working yesterday.

Comment: I see no other reason for this hang. Are you quite sure you get nothing logged? What else is installed on this server?

Comment: http requests are being logged in access.log file, but if i directly try to make https request, they are not being logged. Just another express server is running on port 8082.

Comment: I have added the full parsed configuration file, if that helps.

Comment: Have added the curl output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851018/tls-handshake-timeout-using-letsencrypt-certificate. It seems it is timing out at TLS handshake. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

While this answer does not give a full solution to your problem it hopefully offers some relevant details. Testing with the openssl command line tool and also checking [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=abhaysrivastav.net) shows strange behavior.

The connection works with RSA and DHE key exchange but hangs if ECDHE key exchange is offered:

```
$  openssl s_client -connect abhaysrivastav.net:443  -cipher 'RSA'
...
    Cipher    : AES128-GCM-SHA256

$ openssl s_client -connect abhaysrivastav.net:443  -cipher 'RSA:DHE'
...
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

$ openssl s_client -connect abhaysrivastav.net:443  -cipher 'RSA:DHE:ECDHE'
CONNECTED ...
<hangs>
```

Moreover the connection works only with TLS 1.2 (i.e. option `-tls1_2` but not `-tls1` or `-tls1_1`) even though your config claims to support all of these protocol versions.

But, the config you show is actually only a part of the nginx config. There are several includes which might contain important details. I recommend that you first look into the error log of nginx for anything unexpected and also check if there is some device in front of nginx which might fiddle with the traffic and cause problems, for example some firewall, IPS, WAF, load balancer etc.